# How to install mysql gem on Mac os 10.6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rubygems

i just installed MAMP on this iMac and the rubygems but when i run:

sudo gem install mysql — –with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config

gives me

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/ext/mysql_api/gem_make.out
ERROR:  could not find gem — locally or in a repository
ERROR:  could not find gem –with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config locally or in a repository

how can i install this gem ?

Comment: now i can't get it working on a new mac :S

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this and worked out perfectly:

you can go to  http://www.tmtm.org/en/ruby/mysql/ to download the tar 
file, and run the command below

`# ruby ./install.rb`

to install the mysql.rb

Comment: Well... This command line gives me an error : "./install.rb:9: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config." What's wrong ?

Comment: When I posted this answer I was using Ruby `1.8.7` and maybe I was still using `Rails 3.2.10` but what I recommend now is: 1) Install mysql from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/ then manage your ruby versions with rvm and install your mysql gem through `rvm`. Side note: sometimes you should use `mysql2` gem instead of `mysql` gem.

Answer (score 5):

Use the following it worked with me

```
brew install mysql
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you have the Xcode developer tools installed on Mac OS X?  If not, I'd start there.

You can download them here: http://developer.apple.com/technologies/xcode.html

Once you've installed that, try again.

Answer (score 2):

i'm still getting this

```
$ sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386" gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql_config 
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-mysql-config=/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql_config
checking for mysql_ssl_set()... no
checking for rb_str_set_len()... no
checking for rb_thread_start_timer()... no
checking for mysql.h... no
checking for mysql/mysql.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
    --with-mysql-config

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/ext/mysql_api/gem_make.out

Answer (score 1):

You need the mysql development libs to compile it. If you were on linux you could use "yum install mysql-devel". Not sure about how to get them installed on a mac, but try downloading the connector libraries from here:
[MySql Connector Downloads](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/#downloads)

You may have to pass in a --with-mysql-libs option to point to the directory when the C libraries are unpacked to. Hope this points you in the right direction.

Or you can just put the libraries in the default directory:
/usr/lib64/mysql

Answer (score -1):

Download mysql-dev from mysql.com