# Getting errors when starting a rails server with MySQL on mac os

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, macos

I've been tinkering with this one for several days and I still get the same error. For starters, I have been able to start a newly rails app with sqlite as the database but the application we are working on uses Mysql. So when I go to the app directory and type "rails server" it gives me the following:

```
 /Users/gojinjedi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2.rb:8:in `require': dlopen(/Users/gojinjedi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/gojinjedi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/gojinjedi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
    from /Users/gojinjedi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/gojinjedi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /Users/gojinjedi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/gojinjedi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /Users/gojinjedi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
    from /Users/gojinjedi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /Users/gojinjedi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/gojinjedi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `require'
    from /Users/gojinjedi/Sites/bluey/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/gojinjedi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `require'
    from /Users/gojinjedi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/gojinjedi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
    from /Users/gojinjedi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

So (I think) MySQL development headers aren't installed, which I googled everywhere how to install them and tried most install command line to no success yet. Examples of commands I've tried:

```
gem install mysql2

sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386" gem install mysql --   --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/mysql --with-mysql-lib=/usr/local/mysql/lib   --with-mysql-include=/usr/local/mysql/include
```

I did the bundle install, bundle update and bundle commands in the app directory...I'm running out of options...can you help me?

I'm on mac osx 10.7

Comment: actually you should use `ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"` if you're running MacOS 10.7

Comment: Unfortunately it's still the same message after changing to `"ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716527/how-to-install-mysql-gem-on-mac-os-10-6), I'm one Mac OS X (lion) too and I have no problem with the mysql gem. Or may be you can find what you want [here](http://wonko.com/post/how-to-install-the-mysqlruby-gem-on-mac-os-x-leopard)

**[EDIT]**

Or you can simply use ruby-mysql gem for development environment

Comment: I've tried all this already and it's always giving me the same message as above...missing some items.

Comment: Have you tried with ruby 1.8.7, i have some problem with 1.9.2 too

Comment: The funny thing is I am able to create a new rails app with a different database, but when I try to run our web app which runs on Mysql it doesn't work.

Comment: You try to run localy your web app ? ^^ why didn't you simply use sqlite ! no ?

Comment: Is there a way to change the database type on an app...this app is pretty far out in its development which was started by someone else and now I want to get involve but can't due to these problems with MySQL.

Comment: You can group your gem group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'webrat'
  gem 'cucumber-rails'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end

Comment: Not sure I understand your last suggestion...is this the command I need to type?

Comment: Nop, it's an exemple to use some gems development environment and some other in production